# Why is a drug entity recognized in one text blurb but not another by Amazon Comprehend Medical?

Tags: nlp, amazon-comprehend

When I enter submit this text to Comprehend Medical, it recognizes ibuprofen as GENERIC_NAME :

```
Yesterday, the patient took 200 mg of ibuprofen
```

In this text, however, ibuprofen is not recognized

```
ibuprofen is taken 20 mg po daily for 2 times as tablet
```

Other entities such as dosage, route, frequency, and duration are identified. As a user, can I make any configuration changes such that the drug is recognized in the second instance as well?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the location of dosage being after the drug in the second sentence. Ideally, their model should be able to find ibuprofen in the second sentence too, but maybe their training data wasn't big enough to cover all variations of dosage + drug

reorder the second sentence to be: 20 mg ibuprofen is taken po daily for 2 times as tablet and see if you get what you want.